# Filter excel sheet based on dropdown selection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'd like to filter an Excel sheet by selecting from a dropdown menu.

The worksheet layout looks like this:

```
___________|_Product1_|_Product2_|_Product3_|_Product4_|
Shop1      |    X     |     X    |          |          |
Shop2      |          |     X    |     X    |          |
Shop3      |    X     |          |          |     X    |
           |          |          |          |          |
Ingredient1|          |     X    |          |     X    |
Ingredient2|    X     |     X    |     X    |     X    |
Ingredient3|    X     |          |     X    |          |
```

I'd like to have a dropdown with all shops and depending on the selection only the products marked with an 'X' should be visible (all other columns should be hidden).

Played around with data validation lists but couldn't achieve more than a normal dropdown with the shop names listed inside.

Comment: Use the macro recorder to filter what you want. Then you can edit the code and use a variable for the filter criteria.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a shot. Didn't use the macro recorder yet. Would I have to use it for each shop?

Comment: Pease the share the Code you worked on and specify the exact issue you came across so that SO can help you

Comment: There is no code I worked on as I said I tried it with data validation lists but that didn't lead to success. Will give the macro recorder a try now to work out some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people coming at this site seeking for the same answer, I did it like this now and it works perfectly fine for me. May not be the best solution but at least it's functional:

Created a data validation list with all shops (Shop1, Shop2, Shop3) and a 'Show all' entry. Depending on the selection I call a different macro. To do this I added this code to the worksheet (right-click on the worksheet name -> view code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'$F$2 points to the field containing the data validation list
If Target.Address(True, True) = "$F$2" Then
    Select Case Target
        'this matches against the shop name (string) in the data val. list
        Case "Shop1"
            'this is the macro name
            Call Shop1
        Case "Shop2"
            Call Shop2
        Case "Shop3"
            Call Shop3
        Case "Show all"
            Call ShowAll
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

And created 3 different macros named Shop1, Shop2, Shop3 and ShowAll with the following code:

```
'name your function
Sub Shop1()
Dim LastColumn As Long, x As Long
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'begins to count at column number 2
For x = 2 To LastColumn
   'counts all X in the row number 7
   If UCase(Cells(7, x).Value) = "X" Then
     Columns(x).Hidden = False
   Else
     Columns(x).Hidden = True
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

I just changed the row number to the matching one in the worksheet for every macro (Cells(**7**, x).Value)
For the 'show all' event I just inserted this:

```
Sub ShowAll()
For x = 4 To 40
  Columns(x).Hidden = False
Next
End Sub
```