# Filter a sheet based on the result of a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, validation, filtering

I want to filter a sheet based on a value I select from a drop down list i.e. column C lets me know the file type (Access, Excel etc). I select, from a drop down list on cell G2, what type of file I want and the spreadsheet will filter accordingly

I haven't tried as I'm just learning VBA

Comment: [search for the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148165/filter-excel-sheet-based-on-dropdown-selection)

Comment: From what you describe it sounds like you could do this without VBA. Use a data validation list in cell G2 and use `FILTER()` with a reference to your data table.